# Error Number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a problem when I run my code "without YearlyLimit" then it is run properly but when i add the YearlyLimit in insert query then error occurs

> "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

```
protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Geeta/Desktop/eTimeTrackLite1.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(str);
    conn.Open();
    string query = "insert into LeaveTypes (LeaveTypeFName,LeaveTypeSName,YearlyLimit,Gender) values ('" + txt_leavetypename.Text + "', '" + txt_shortname.Text + "', '" + txt_yearlimit.Text + "', '" + Convert.ToString(rdbtn_all.Checked) + "', '" + Convert.ToString(rdbtn_male.Checked) + "', '" + Convert.ToString(rdbtn_female.Checked) + "')";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    BindGridData();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046238/number-of-query-values-and-destination-fields-are-not-the-same-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add too many items into the record

1. LeaveTypeFName
2. LeaveTypeSName
3. YearlyLimit
4. Gender

You are trying to insert

1. txt_leavetypename.Text
2. txt_shortname.Text
3. txt_yearlimit.Text
4. Convert.ToString(rdbtn_all.Checked)
5. Convert.ToString(rdbtn_male.Checked)
6. Convert.ToString(rdbtn_female.Checked)

you need to make a check on which item you want to go into the last field